# Programmatically removes files/folder resides in docker container

Tags: docker

I am currently exploring on how we can remove the file/folder resides inside docker container programmatically . I know we can copy files from container to host using docker cp. However, I am looking for something like docker mv or docker rm which allows me to move or remove files/folders inside docker.

The scenario is, We are writing the automated test cases in Java and for one case we need to copy the log file from the server's log folder to assert the log written by the test case. We are using the docker cp to copy the log files. However it contains the log of old test cases as well. So I was thinking if I can remove the log files before executing my test case. It make sure the log I have copied is written by my test case only. Is there any other way around?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can use below command to remove the files from program running on host

```
docker exec <container> rm -rf <YourFile>
```

However if old files exist because the container were never removed, then general practice is to remove the container once the all test suite execution is complete,

New job should create the new container.

Comment: Thanks Sudhir, I agree with you.

Comment: What if the container is not running? `docker cp ...` can copy files into a container that's not running, so I would assume it's possible to also _remove_ files from a stopped container, no?

Comment: Notice that we can't use wildcard : `docker exec <container> rm -rf foldel/foo*` doesn't work, alternative is to have volume with host and create CRON at host !

Answer (score 5):

In the docker file definition you can use

`RUN rm [folder-path]`

However anything added using ADD or COPY will still increase the size of your image.

EDIT: For accessing a running container from an external program running on your host try this.

1. Mount a host folder as a volume when starting the instance.
2. Run a script or program on the host to delete desired folders on the host which will affect the container file system as well.

Comment: Thanks Santanu, but it won't help as I need to do it programmatically on running instance of docker.

Comment: @JimitJoshi you may want to try mounting a host folder as a volume inside your docker instance when launching it? Then you can delete it from any program running on the host.

Comment: Yes Santanu, we do have a host folder as a volume inside docker. But the log files are written in different location. I have updated my ans in above comment. thanks for taking time and comment.

Answer (score 3):

You can access the container bash console

```
#console control over container
docker exec -it a5866aee4e90 bash
```

Then when you are inside the container you can do anything with console.
Im using this command to find and rename files in my jboss deployments directory. Modify it how you need to serve you. You can delete files also insted of mv use rm

```
find /home/jboss/jbossas/standalone/deployments -depth -name "*.failed" -exec sh -c 'mv "$1" "${1%.failed}.dodeploy"' _ {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The way you mentioned will definitely work from host machine. However I am looking to delete files using Java program. I can run the command "docker exec -it a5866aee4e90 bash" through Java program but the subsequent command to delete the file wont run inside the docker bash. I believe It will run on host only. I will give it a try.

Comment: I always get "OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "bash": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown" from this command